# What's the best way to read cookies via CURL?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I'm testing the CURL capacity to read cookies on a random page by running:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://www.forocoches.com/foro/showthread.php?t=7903192');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $matches);
$cookies = array();
foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
    parse_str($item, $cookie);
    $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
}
```

I would expect to get something like:

```
"__cfduid", "_fbp", "_ga", "_gid", "bblastactivity", "bblastvisit", "freewheel-detected-bandwidth", "GED_PLAYLIST_ACTIVITY", "sas_euconsent_v2"
```

But I only get:

```
"bblastactivity", "bblastvisit", "__cfduid"
```

Is that because the others take longer to be dropped? Is there anything I can do to catch them?

Comment: ive just checked that url, and its only setting them 3 cookies which your curl is seeing

Comment: That's odd, I've just opened a new incognito window with that URL, the EditThisCookie plugin is finding all the others I mention - @LawrenceCherone do you have any ad blocker enabled?

Comment: maybe you have extensions doing something. Don't use a browser use postman and your see https://i.imgur.com/n3vmyN6.png

Comment: Postman as CURL seems to be missing Google Analytics or FB cookies that are dropped while loading the page (asynchronously I guess) - those cookies do not seem to be generated by any extension

Comment: sure they could be dropped in by other requests but the url you provided does not set the other cookies and curl wont render js to then look for other set cookies as curl is not a browser, EditThisCookie would be combining all set cookies, you need to be looking on first line of network tab and in headers section

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that out - is there any other way of getting those cookies? How does cookiebot do it for instance? ‍♂️

Comment: probably a headless browser